# Passing values from array(list) to another form

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, list, parameter-passing

I have an array in `form1`

```
var arr = new List<double>();
```

Also I have `form2`. In `button_Click` I wrote:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

I need to pass the array to `form2`. I need use values from this array in another form.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Remember that Form2 is a class, you can implement a public or internal method...and you can pass the list...For example: form2.SetArray(arr);

Comment: @Maria SO is full of this kind of questions. Have you read any one of them?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, its not an array... its a list. Backed by an array yes.. but not actually an array.

Pass your list into the constructor for `Form2`:

```
var form2 = new Form2(arr); // pass it in
```

Then in your `Form2` constructor.. accept the list:

```
private IList<double> _theList;

public Form2(IList<double> list) {
    _theList = list;
}
```

Then use `_theList` in your second form.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in the constructor of Form2:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(arr);
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Then in the Form2 constructor:

```
public Form2(List<double> arr)
{
   //do stuff with it here
}
```